# Removing more than one random item from a list

Tags: python

Trying to figure out how to remove more than one random item from a list. Here's the code i have.

```
playerdeck = random.sample(cardlist, 7)
print(playerdeck, "\n")
cardlist.remove(playerdeck[0,6])
print(cardlist)
```

Although this below actually works just fine, I was not sure how to do it in a range.

```
cardlist.remove(playerdeck[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it with a list comprehension.

```
playerdeck = random.sample(cardlist, 7)
print(playerdeck, "\n")
cardlist = [i for i in cardlist if i not in playerdeck]
print(cardlist)
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about this? Note `playerdeck[0,6]`.

Comment: Sorry, actually I've just worked with OP's code. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to shuffle a deck and then transfer some cards to the player's hand:

```
random.shuffle(cardlist)
playerdeck = cardlist[-7:]
cardlist[-7:] = []
```